# SP2010 Filter view of a list webpart with a people picker?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

This is SharePoint 2010 environment.  I'm trying to do the following without making a custom webpart (no VS).  I will only have SP Designer and Infopath

I have a webpart page that displays a list that has a column called Assigned To that displays a username filled in using a people picker.
I would like to be able to get a filter webpart on the page that is a people picker that a user can fill in and it will filter the view of the list to only display the items that match the Assigned To field with the user supplied people picker entry.
Again I can user SPD or Infopath or anything OOTB but have no access to VS.

Is this possible without resorting to a custom made webpart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in front of SharePoint right now, but you could try one of the filter web parts as described on [this Microsoft page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/sharepoint-foundation-help/work-with-filter-web-parts-HA101794720.aspx)

Or, if you turn to the list view, you can enable the metadata navigation panel, to which you can add the desired people field. (This feature requires the Enterprise license and the managed metadata service).

Comment: I've  been messing with the filter web parts but not quite how I hoped to have it work.  I will check into the metadata navigation panel.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Metadata navigation won't quite work out for me and it doesn't display when using a webpart page either.  I'm going to look into maybe trying a Infopath form solution instead.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Here is an approach how to get metadata navigation showing on a web part page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/web_part_page_and_metadata_navigation/archive/2012/05/16/web-part-page-and-metadata-navigation.aspx